# How to find the root cause of a JVM Crash caused by native code

Tags: java, tomcat, azure, jvm, java-native-interface

We have an web application running with Tomcat in a Microsoft Azure Environment. We are not using any native libraries or external dlls in our code.

From time to time the JVM crashes with

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:149), pid=3580, tid=4088 # guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
```

Looking at the hs_err_pid files it looks like the error is triggered by generating PDF using the itext library used in the web application.

Typically such events are listed in "Compiliation events" in the pif files:

```
Event: 195606.307 Thread 0x000000000ea60000 3550            com.itextpdf.text.io.IndependentRandomAccessSource::get (11 bytes)
Event: 195606.307 Thread 0x000000000ea5b000 3551            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray::read (42 bytes)
```

We are not able to reproduce the problem even by using all available parameters used by our customer. Between the occurrences of this problem sometimes weeks ore months pass. But if the problem occurs on one cluster node and the load balancer redirects the current web application user to the second cluster node the problem occurs on this node also, so no running nodes are left and the web application is not available anymore.

We have no session replication between the nodes, so a redirected user has to log in again on the second node. But it seems that something in the environment let the user action make crashing the second node also.

We have already tried without success to solve this problem by switching the JVM versions, even downgrading from 1.7 to 1.6 and also changing Tomcat versions.

According to this bug http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6961186 , the error is caused by native code. The Windows event logs on the servers do not show any error at the time the error occurs.

Does anyone has an idea how the root cause of this problem can be found?

Christoph

Following a complete hs_err_pid file

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:143), pid=2640, tid=4388
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Call to MiniDumpWriteDump() failed
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000013761800):  JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-29" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=4388, stack(0x00000000178d0000,0x00000000179d0000)]

Stack: [0x00000000178d0000,0x00000000179d0000]

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000123a3000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-41" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4148, stack(0x0000000017750000,0x0000000017850000)]
  0x00000000123a4000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-40" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3516, stack(0x0000000016f40000,0x0000000017040000)]
  0x00000000123a2800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-39" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2192, stack(0x0000000012780000,0x0000000012880000)]
  0x000000001375b800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-37" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2564, stack(0x0000000014bb0000,0x0000000014cb0000)]
  0x0000000013763000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-35" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3520, stack(0x0000000017c00000,0x0000000017d00000)]
  0x000000001375d000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-34" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4964, stack(0x00000000175b0000,0x00000000176b0000)]
  0x0000000013763800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-33" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4776, stack(0x0000000017ab0000,0x0000000017bb0000)]
=>0x0000000013761800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-29" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=4388, stack(0x00000000178d0000,0x00000000179d0000)]
  0x000000001375e800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-20" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5068, stack(0x0000000010d90000,0x0000000010e90000)]
  0x00000000123a1000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3916, stack(0x00000000180a0000,0x00000000181a0000)]
  0x0000000013764800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4636, stack(0x00000000170b0000,0x00000000171b0000)]
  0x000000001375a800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4020, stack(0x00000000171d0000,0x00000000172d0000)]
  0x000000001375a000 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3272, stack(0x0000000015760000,0x0000000015860000)]
  0x0000000013759000 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3904, stack(0x0000000015da0000,0x0000000015ea0000)]
  0x0000000013758000 JavaThread "QuartzScheduler_ClixScheduler-RD000D3A2038D11417231481897_MisfireHandler" [_thread_blocked, id=1108, stack(0x0000000015ca0000,0x0000000015da0000)]
  0x0000000013757800 JavaThread "QuartzScheduler_ClixScheduler-RD000D3A2038D11417231481897_ClusterManager" [_thread_in_native, id=2460, stack(0x0000000015a20000,0x0000000015b20000)]
  0x0000000013756800 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=3892, stack(0x0000000015b80000,0x0000000015c80000)]
  0x0000000013756000 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=3288, stack(0x0000000015880000,0x0000000015980000)]
  0x00000000130d7000 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=3508, stack(0x0000000015630000,0x0000000015730000)]
  0x00000000130d6800 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=2312, stack(0x0000000015430000,0x0000000015530000)]
  0x00000000130d5800 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=3780, stack(0x00000000103b0000,0x00000000104b0000)]
  0x00000000130d5000 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=712, stack(0x000000000f960000,0x000000000fa60000)]
  0x00000000130d4000 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3700, stack(0x00000000152a0000,0x00000000153a0000)]
  0x00000000130d3800 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=668, stack(0x00000000150f0000,0x00000000151f0000)]
  0x00000000130d2800 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3500, stack(0x0000000014eb0000,0x0000000014fb0000)]
  0x00000000130d2000 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3376, stack(0x0000000014cc0000,0x0000000014dc0000)]
  0x00000000130d1000 JavaThread "ClixScheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3788, stack(0x0000000013c90000,0x0000000013d90000)]
  0x00000000130d0800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2932, stack(0x0000000013b30000,0x0000000013c30000)]
  0x000000000ea61800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1612, stack(0x00000000105e0000,0x00000000106e0000)]
  0x000000000ea60000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3100, stack(0x0000000010720000,0x0000000010820000)]
  0x000000000ea5b000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2724, stack(0x00000000104b0000,0x00000000105b0000)]
  0x000000000ea59000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3924, stack(0x00000000102a0000,0x00000000103a0000)]
  0x000000000ea52000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2288, stack(0x0000000010190000,0x0000000010290000)]
  0x000000000e9f7000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2692, stack(0x000000000fbf0000,0x000000000fcf0000)]
  0x000000000e9ee000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3292, stack(0x000000000fd30000,0x000000000fe30000)]
  0x0000000000d7b000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3360, stack(0x00000000010c0000,0x00000000011c0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000e9ec800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000000faa0000,0x000000000fba0000] [id=3092]
  0x000000000ea6b000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000010c50000,0x0000000010d50000] [id=3344]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
PSYoungGen      total 1304576K, used 1047669K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1218048K, 85% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007ea81e7a8,0x00000007f5000000)
  from space 86528K, 1% used [0x00000007f5000000,0x00000007f517ec78,0x00000007fa480000)
  to   space 81408K, 0% used [0x00000007fb080000,0x00000007fb080000,0x0000000800000000)
ParOldGen       total 2796544K, used 106067K [0x00000006fff80000, 0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 2796544K, 3% used [0x00000006fff80000,0x0000000706714cd0,0x00000007aaa80000)
PSPermGen       total 86528K, used 86406K [0x00000006eff80000, 0x00000006f5400000, 0x00000006fff80000)
  object space 86528K, 99% used [0x00000006eff80000,0x00000006f53e1b00,0x00000006f5400000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000041c0000,0x0000000004a50000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000000a40400

Polling page: 0x0000000000430000

Code Cache  [0x00000000011c0000, 0x0000000001e10000, 0x00000000041c0000)
total_blobs=3864 nmethods=3166 adapters=649 free_code_cache=36823Kb largest_free_block=37465664

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 195605.051 Thread 0x000000000ea60000 3547             com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.PngImage::decodeUpFilter (41 bytes)
Event: 195605.058 Thread 0x000000000ea60000 nmethod 3547 0x0000000001c447d0 code [0x0000000001c44900, 0x0000000001c44a18]
Event: 195605.059 Thread 0x000000000ea5b000 nmethod 3546% 0x0000000001ddb410 code [0x0000000001ddb560, 0x0000000001ddb9b8]
Event: 195605.406 Thread 0x000000000ea60000 3548             java.io.DataInputStream::readFully (63 bytes)
Event: 195605.408 Thread 0x000000000ea60000 nmethod 3548 0x0000000001de8150 code [0x0000000001de82a0, 0x0000000001de8398]
Event: 195605.568 Thread 0x000000000ea5b000 3549 %           com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.PngImage::decodeAverageFilter @ 50 (110 bytes)
Event: 195605.574 Thread 0x000000000ea5b000 nmethod 3549% 0x0000000001de60d0 code [0x0000000001de6220, 0x0000000001de6558]
Event: 195606.307 Thread 0x000000000ea60000 3550             com.itextpdf.text.io.IndependentRandomAccessSource::get (11 bytes)
Event: 195606.307 Thread 0x000000000ea5b000 3551             com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray::read (42 bytes)
Event: 195606.310 Thread 0x000000000ea60000 nmethod 3550 0x0000000001de5a10 code [0x0000000001de5b80, 0x0000000001de5da8]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 186200.029 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=23 (full 0):
PSYoungGen      total 1285120K, used 1166466K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1165824K, 100% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007f1d00000,0x00000007f1d00000)
  from space 119296K, 0% used [0x00000007f8b80000,0x00000007f8c208c0,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 113152K, 0% used [0x00000007f1d00000,0x00000007f1d00000,0x00000007f8b80000)
  ... skipped GC part because of question length limit

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 195606.300 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001d732f0 method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.length()J @ 4
Event: 195606.300 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001d82d7c method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read([BII)I @ 56
Event: 195606.300 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000012b2eac method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read()I @ 36
Event: 195606.300 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001d82d7c method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read([BII)I @ 56
Event: 195606.300 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001d82d7c method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read([BII)I @ 56
Event: 195606.300 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001d82d7c method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read([BII)I @ 56
Event: 195606.300 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001d73a60 method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read([BII)I @ 56
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000014cccc4 method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read()I @ 36
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001d732f0 method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.length()J @ 4
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000001d732f0 method=com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.length()J @ 4

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 195606.279 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7aa4e0 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.279 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7aad90 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.281 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7b5fc0 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.281 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7b69d0 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.291 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7d9478 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.291 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7d9d98 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.296 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7e38e8 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.296 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7e4240 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.299 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7f05a8 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 195606.299 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Threw 0x00000007ea7f0fb8 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 195606.300 Thread 0x0000000013761800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000011f75a4 sp=0x00000000179ce210 mode 2
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffffde fr.pc=0x00000000014cccc4
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000014cccc4 sp=0x00000000179ce350
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000011f75a4 sp=0x00000000179ce2a0 mode 2
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffffde fr.pc=0x0000000001d732f0
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000001d732f0 sp=0x00000000179ce350
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000011f75a4 sp=0x00000000179ce210 mode 2
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffffde fr.pc=0x0000000001d732f0
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000001d732f0 sp=0x00000000179ce350
Event: 195606.309 Thread 0x0000000013761800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000011f75a4 sp=0x00000000179ce210 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fd80000 - 0x000000013fdb3000     c:\appserver\environment\java7\bin\java.exe
0x0000000077ba0000 - 0x0000000077d49000     D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077a80000 - 0x0000000077b9f000     D:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefde40000 - 0x000007fefdeac000     D:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefe5b0000 - 0x000007fefe68b000     D:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefe0e0000 - 0x000007fefe17f000     D:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feff520000 - 0x000007feff53f000     D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe180000 - 0x000007fefe2ad000     D:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077980000 - 0x0000000077a7a000     D:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefe6a0000 - 0x000007fefe707000     D:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe0d0000 - 0x000007fefe0de000     D:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff8e0000 - 0x000007feff9a9000     D:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefc530000 - 0x000007fefc724000     D:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefe530000 - 0x000007fefe5a1000     D:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007feff4a0000 - 0x000007feff4ce000     D:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007feffb40000 - 0x000007feffc49000     D:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000073080000 - 0x0000000073152000     c:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000072330000 - 0x0000000072af9000     c:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefa770000 - 0x000007fefa779000     D:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007feff4d0000 - 0x000007feff51d000     D:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe690000 - 0x000007fefe698000     D:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef1580000 - 0x000007fef15bb000     D:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000077d70000 - 0x0000000077d77000     D:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000073070000 - 0x000000007307f000     c:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000073040000 - 0x0000000073068000     c:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000073020000 - 0x0000000073035000     c:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefe710000 - 0x000007feff498000     D:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007feff540000 - 0x000007feff743000     D:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x0000000073000000 - 0x0000000073019000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefd2a0000 - 0x000007fefd2f5000     D:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefd500000 - 0x000007fefd507000     D:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x0000000072fe0000 - 0x0000000072ff1000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000072fd0000 - 0x0000000072fdb000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\management.dll
0x000007fefd410000 - 0x000007fefd428000     D:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefd010000 - 0x000007fefd057000     D:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefdaa0000 - 0x000007fefdaaf000     D:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefd990000 - 0x000007fefd99f000     D:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefc440000 - 0x000007fefc455000     D:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef1ba0000 - 0x000007fef1bb5000     D:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefd130000 - 0x000007fefd18b000     D:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef2ae0000 - 0x000007fef2aeb000     D:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefccc0000 - 0x000007fefccc7000     D:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefbd30000 - 0x000007fefbd57000     D:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefbd10000 - 0x000007fefbd1b000     D:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef4430000 - 0x000007fef4438000     D:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefbaf0000 - 0x000007fefbb43000     D:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x0000000072fa0000 - 0x0000000072fc4000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\sunec.dll
0x0000000072f90000 - 0x0000000072f9b000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x000007fefdcb0000 - 0x000007fefde1d000     D:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefdb40000 - 0x000007fefdb4f000     D:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000000006f590000 - 0x000000006f725000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fefded0000 - 0x000007fefdfa7000     D:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000000006f560000 - 0x000000006f590000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\jpeg.dll
0x0000000072f40000 - 0x0000000072f86000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x0000000072ef0000 - 0x0000000072f31000     C:\appserver\environment\java7\jre\bin\t2k.dll
0x000007fefb330000 - 0x000007fefb455000     D:\Windows\system32\DBGHELP.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin -Xloggc:C:\appserver\clix2013\logs\gc.log -Djava.util.logging.config.file=c:\appserver\environment\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\conf\logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=c:\appserver\environment\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\endorsed -Dcatalina.base=c:\appserver\environment\apache-tomcat-7.0.39 -Dcatalina.home=c:\appserver\environment\apache-tomcat-7.0.39 -Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\appserver\environment\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\temp
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JRE_HOME=c:\appserver\environment\java7
CLASSPATH=c:\appserver\environment\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin\bootstrap.jar;c:\appserver\environment\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
USERNAME=SYSTEM
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 7339576k(4195404k free), swap 11532016k(5234796k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_45-b18), built on Oct  8 2013 05:47:22 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Mon Dec 01 10:44:13 2014
elapsed time: 195609 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this line in the  hs_err_pid
Failed to write core dump. Call to MiniDumpWriteDump() failed
I would suggest investigating and fixing this problem first - i.e so that the entire details of the core dump are written out. That would give more information about the reason for the crash.
Also do you have the tomcat apr native connector set up? If not, that might be one reason for the entire core dump not getting written out.

Comment: But we have also have crashes, where minidump files are created (# Core dump written. Default location: D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin\hs_err_pid10600.mdmp). But we found no way to open the files (for example with Visual Studio) as the files are reported as corrupt. We have already created a Microsoft support ticket for this, but they were not able to help in this case. We tried also to get readable minidumps with "-XX:OnError="userdump.exe %%p D:/dump.mdmp", but this hasn't changed the situation.

Comment: I can open a minidump file with a text editor and there are entries like this: sun.ci.lastMethod com/itextpdf/text/io/IndependentRandomAccessSource get

Answer (score 0):

Crash occured

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:149), pid=3580, tid=4088 # guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
```

Guarantee failure indicate there is an native(C++) exception that propogated back to VM, lead to unexpected failure. 
Closing as Not an issue 
VM cannot do anything here, there is an enhancement to handle the error message in an informative way through [JDK-8180347](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180347)